# Error: Body attribute missing in multipart while using googleapis node module

Tags: node.js, request, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

i am using drive version2 to insert a new file to google-drive.
To insert a new file to a google drive using client.files.insert() function

i am getting the following error
Error: Body attribute missing in multipart.

```
var auth = new googleapis.OAuth2Client();

auth.setCredentials({
   access_token: 'accesskey'
});

googleapis.discover('drive', 'v2').execute(function(err, client) {
    client.drive.files.insert({ title: 'Test', mimeType: 'application/json' })
    .withMedia('application/json', "Hello world")
    .withAuthClient(auth)
    .execute(function(error,result){
    if(error){
       console.log(error);
    }else{
       console.log(result);
    }
 });
```

the above code is there in documentation : https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/

can any on help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the Drive API:

- Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
- Select a project.
- Select **APIs & auth** in the left sidebar.
- Find the *Drive API* in the list of available APIs and set its status to **ON**.